# How to find ngram frequency of a column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk, text-mining

Below is the input pandas dataframe I have.

[image]

I want to find the frequency of unigrams & bigrams. A sample of what I am expecting is shown below[image]

How to do this using nltk or scikit learn?

I wrote the below code which takes a string as input. How to extend it to series/dataframe?

```
from nltk.collocations import *
desc='john is a guy person you him guy person you him'
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(desc)
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
finder.ngram_fd.viewitems()
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If your data is like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    'must watch. Good acting',
    'average movie. Bad acting',
    'good movie. Good acting',
    'pathetic. Avoid',
    'avoid'], columns=['description'])
```

You could use the `CountVectorizer` of the package `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), analyzer='word')
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['description'])
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])
```

Which gives you :

```
                frequency
good            3
pathetic        1
average movie   1
movie bad       2
watch           1
good movie      1
watch good      3
good acting     2
must            1
movie good      2
pathetic avoid  1
bad acting      1
average         1
must watch      1
acting          1
bad             1
movie           1
avoid           1
```

**EDIT**

`fit` will just "train" your vectorizer : it will split the words of your corpus and create a vocabulary with it. Then `transform` can take a new document and create vector of frequency based on the vectorizer vocabulary.

Here your training set is your output set, so you can do both at the same time (`fit_transform`). Because you have 5 documents, it will create 5 vectors as a matrix. You want a global vector, so you have to make a `sum`.

**EDIT 2**

For big dataframes, you can speed up the frequencies computation by using:

```
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).data
```

or

```
frequencies = sparse_matrix.sum(axis=0).T
```

Comment: +1 Can you explain difference between fit_transform() / fit() / transform()? How did you figure out that sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0] gives the frequencies? I didnt find much info regrading this in the scikit learn documentation.

Comment: @ML_Pro I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Marked as answer. Very helpful explanation.

Comment: very elegant way, but the '`sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]`' command takes ages with a big dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @FernandoS.Peregrino. Could you try `frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).data` ?

Comment: Huge speed increase with @Till last suggestion

Comment: Cool I will update the answer ! Thanks again for the remark.

Comment: @Till - `sum(sparse_matrix).data` gave me wrong frequencies.

Comment: The error you get if you have `Nan`'s in your column can be solved with `sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['description'].dropna())`

Comment: Something seems wrong here. I got a frequency count of 2 for the value `05ric`, but when I did `df[(df['title_type'].str.contains('05ric', na=False, regex=False))]` I got no rows back. I copied and pasted the `05ric`.

Comment: the sum is way too slow.  You can do `frequencies = sparse_matrix.sum(axis=0).T`

Comment: @Till if `good` is appearing in bigrams then how can I exclude it from appearing in unigram. It should appear in unigram only if it appears alone.