# How to append strings to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have the following code to extract sentences out of a directory of text files.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import pandas as pd

directory_in_str = "E:\\Extracted\\"
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    with open(os.path.join(directory_in_str, filename), encoding="utf8") as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            sentences = sent_tokenize(line)
```

I would like to build up a pandas dataframe and append the sentences to that dataframe so that I can build a frequency count of the n-grams in the sentences as per [How to find ngram frequency of a column in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572221/how-to-find-ngram-frequency-of-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

That is to say I need to append the sentences to `df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['description'])` so that I can then do:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), analyzer='word')
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['description'])
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])
```

What would be the code to append the sentences to the `df` Dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extraction code needs a slight change. Declare `sentences` outside and keep `extend`ing it as needed.

```
sentences = []
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    with open(os.path.join(directory_in_str, filename), encoding="utf8") as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            sentences.extend(sent_tokenize(line))
```

Once done, simply initialise your `df` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Description' : sentences})
```

Comment: If I do `ngram_freq = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])` and `df.index.name='ngram'` and `ngram_freq[ngram_freq.ngram == 'youtube']` I can't get the frequency count for youtube. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Superdooperhero Did you mean to do: `ngram_freq[ngram_freq.index =='youtube']`?

Comment: Yes sorry that should be `ngram_freq.index.name = 'ngram'`

Comment: Got it with `ngram_freq.loc['youtube'].frequency`