# Wrong result in Count vectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, countvectorizer

I'm was trying out the answer in this link:
[How to find ngram frequency of a column in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572221/how-to-find-ngram-frequency-of-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

I'm getting correct result.

But in my own data, I'm getting wrong result:

My data contains 2 instances of "like say":

```
would like say got excellent
adult like say stylish reading
```

But when using count vectorizer

```
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2),analyzer='word')
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(data_copy['2018-1-1']['comment'])
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).data
df_count=pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])
```

The result I'm getting is 340 instances of "like say".

All the bigram frequencies are wrong

Comment: Can you make a minimal example with the wrong count?

Comment: I'm putting the data frame in fit_transform, and summing the frequency then putting it in dataframe. That's it. In the Link which I've shared , the result of frequency is correct but mine is not.

Answer (score -1):

Solved.
Changed the line:

```
sum(sparse_matrix).data
```

To:

```
sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
```

I do not know what's the reason though